# Zabbix 6 agent problem: failed to initialize builtin counter

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-api

I am doing a zabbix 6 installation and configuration of a Windows machine, after installing and configuring the zabbix agent, everything seems to work fine. But after a few hours everything fails and the light turns red, I check the zabbix_agentd.log on the windows machine and I see the following error:

3144:20230824:115158.477 **** Enabled features ****
3144:20230824:115158.478 IPv6 support:          YES
3144:20230824:115158.479 TLS support:           YES
3144:20230824:115158.480 **************************
3144:20230824:115158.481 using configuration file: C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\zabbix_agentd.conf
3144:20230824:115159.012 Failed to initialize builtin counter: % Processor Time
3144:20230824:115159.013 Failed to initialize builtin counter: Total Sessions

4108:20230824:115253.910 Unhandled exception c0000005 detected at 0x00007FFE7C864EAB. Crashing ...

What might be the problem? How could it be solved?